# Why is my Python app not compatible with Heroku's Python buildpack

Tags: python, heroku

I know this has been asked multiple times before but none of the answers seem to work for my particular case. I created a new Github repository and uploaded the following files to it via the Github desktop client (I tried uploading from the website as well):

- Counter.py
- Procfile
- requirments.txt

The app itself works when I test it locally. This is the Procfile:

```
worker: python Counter.py
```

requirments.txt:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

I receive the following error every time I try to deploy it from my Github repository:

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack- 
registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
   More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
!     Push failed
```

I just don't understand why it isn't compatible with the buildpack but every other app I made is. I tried deploying other apps from other repositories and it worked just fine. Thanks for reading.

Comment: `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` might be causing problems. Run `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt` Also not sure if it is a typo but you did the same typo twice. It's `requirements.txt` not `requirments.txt`.

Comment: @TinNguyen Looks like it was the typo in requirements.txt that was causing this. I corrected it and it works now. Thanks for pointing that out and feel free to turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `requirments.txt` twice instead of `requirements.txt`.